# UIView (iOS) in Android Studio

Tags: android

In iOS there is an UIView:
[image]

This UIView, both view A and B, have there own coordinate system. In Android, view A is always the root view (ConstrainyLayout/Linear/Relative). I am using ConstraintLayout and I want to add something like an UIView, but I can not find it. There is something called "View", but I can't add anything into it. What is the best way to add a custom view which hold a group of views? Is it nessecary to create for every view a new .xml file?

I want to bring an View to front and to the back sometimes in my app. It is easier if I just can call 1 view to the front which holds 5 buttons, rather than call 5 times the buttons to the front.

Comment: Try playing with `ViewGroup`s?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to play this margins, padding, height, width of any type of ViewGroup like if you want to add ViewB into or over ViewA do something like this and you will have to study different types of ViewGroups like [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html), [LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html),[ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="250dp"></LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

No it is not at all necessary to create you views always in the .xml.
For the second part yes you can put your five buttons in one view and programmatically move then backward and forward with the below code.

```
public void moveForward() {
        int childCount = mParentLayoutOfTheView.getChildCount();
        if (childCount > 1) {
            int index = mParentLayoutOfTheView.indexOfChild(mChildLayout);
            if (index < childCount - 1) {
                mParentLayoutOfTheView.removeView(mChildLayout);
                mParentLayoutOfTheView.addView(mChildLayout, index + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Move backwards

```
public void moveBackward() {
        int childCount = mParentLayoutOfTheView.getChildCount();
        if (childCount > 1) {
            int index = mParentLayoutOfTheView.indexOfChild(mChildLayout);
            if (index > 0) {
                mParentLayoutOfTheView.removeView(mChildLayout);
                mParentLayoutOfTheView.addView(mChildLayout, index - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.